# Prevent merging branch in master if behind by commits

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to prevent merging the branch into master if its behind by any commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after the `--ff-only` parameter which only allows merges if they are fast-forward and thus do not have any commits in the merge target that are not yet in the merge source.

Comment: Ah, sure, but then you should use another technique, depending on what and where exactly you want to check. e. g. check that the merge target is part of the history of merge source.

Comment: Sure. Let me check whats best place to implement it. our deployment team uses web version of git for merging into master. If this doesnt work then check at deployment in jenkins should be the good place. 
Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: There is no web version of Git. You are using some other tool like GitHub, GitLab or Bitbucket Server. As it is GitHub you are using accoring to your tags and you say you merge via UI, not from commandline, then you can configure at project level which merge options are available. I think there is on that only allows fast-forward merges.